# My Login System in Node.js is not working

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using Node.js and MySQL for a login system. My problem is, login system is not working when I use async-await and promises. It's not giving errors but page keeps reloading and user cannot enter the system. What can the problem be? Is there a problem in my await declarations. I'm kind of new at fullstack programming. Thanks for your help.

At the top of the login controller, there is a async arrow function and below its code block, there are multiple awaits which are defined for some database calls and bcrypting password.

Should I return the database connection as .promise()
or not a promise? Sometimes code is working and user can enter, but sometimes cannot.

**This Code Block For User Login**

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // if (!email || !password) {
    //   return res.status(400).render("giriş_yap", {
    //     msg: "Lütfen e-mail veya şifrenizi giriniz",
    //     msg_type: "error",
    //   });
    // }

    const allDB = await login_db.query(`select * from users where email='${email}'`); 
    const user = allDB[0] ; 
    //console.log(user[0]) ; 
    if (user.length <= 0) {
      return res.status(401).render("giriş_yap", {
        msg: "Sistemde kaydınız bulunamadı",
        msg_type: "error",
      });
    } else {
      const passwordMatch = (await bcrypt.compare(password, user[0].PASS))
      if (!passwordMatch) {
        return res.status(401).render("giriş_yap", {
          msg: "Emailiniz veya Şifreniz hatalı",
          msg_type: "error",
        });
      } else {
        const id = user[0].ID;
        const token =jwt.sign({ id: id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
          expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
        });
        //console.log("The Token is " + token);
        const cookieOptions = {
          expires: new Date(
            Date.now() +
              process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
          ),
          httpOnly: true,
        };
        res.cookie("joes", token, cookieOptions);
        res.status(200).redirect("/anasayfa");
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

**This Code Block for mysql database connection**

```
const mySql = require("mysql2");
const config = require("../config_db");
const login_db = mySql.createConnection(config.db_login);

login_db.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  console.log("Kullanici bilgileri veritabanina başariyla baglandiniz.");
});

module.exports = login_db.promise();
```

Comment: Please include the frontend code.

Comment: can you share your project git repo link?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't forget in your front-end this code ?

```
e.preventDefault()
```

If not, please share the front-end code also.
Also in your code, be careful with your console.log in the catch block on your login function. It can throw to infinite api call.